# Solidity compiler,error:not found browser IERC20.sol

Tags: solidity, error, compiler

Who can halp me with error and codig fleshloan?
I try use for my contract http://remix.etherium.org and i have a promlem with compiller,i use code from official docs aave https://www.docs.aave.com/developers/guides//flesh-loans and pragma solidity compiler 0.6.12 dispey me error: Not found browser /IERC20.sol.
I think a have a promlem with import....,and it promlem for me!
I dont understand this error and what can i do.
My start fragmets code:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12 ;

import { FlashLoanReceiverBase }  from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol"  ;
import { ILendingPool }  from "./ILendingPool.sol"  ;
import { ILendingPoolAddressesProvider } from "./ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol"  ;
import { IERC20 } from "./IERC20.sol  ;

contract Myv2 is FleshLoanReceiverBase {

  function ...........
```

I think remix compiler dont see this 4 import!
Please to help me .

Comment: Hi there. Do you have the other 4 contracts in your Remix folder?

Comment: Okay, you will need to pull in even more separate contracts as well as those 4: https://docs.aave.com/developers/guides/flash-loans/iflashloanreceiver#flashloanreceiverbase